# how many bytes does live media server send each time while streaming

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, streaming, live, rtsp

i have the following code of live media libraries as i was trying to understand it,i was **wondering to find out how many bytes does the live media server send each time of the video file test1.264 while streaming it??
How to find out the streaming time,i pulled out my hairs but was not able to find out,can any one help me to find the above queries....**

```
#include "liveMedia.hh"
#include "BasicUsageEnvironment.hh"

UsageEnvironment* env;

// To make the second and subsequent client for each stream reuse the same
// input stream as the first client (rather than playing the file from the
// start for each client), change the following "False" to "True":
Boolean reuseFirstSource = False;

// To stream *only* MPEG-1 or 2 video "I" frames
// (e.g., to reduce network bandwidth),
// change the following "False" to "True":
Boolean iFramesOnly = False;

static void announceStream(RTSPServer* rtspServer, ServerMediaSession* sms,
               char const* streamName, char const* inputFileName); // fwd

static char newMatroskaDemuxWatchVariable;
static MatroskaFileServerDemux* demux;
static void onMatroskaDemuxCreation(MatroskaFileServerDemux* newDemux, void* /*clientData*/) {
  demux = newDemux;
  newMatroskaDemuxWatchVariable = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
  TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
  env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

  UserAuthenticationDatabase* authDB = NULL;
#ifdef ACCESS_CONTROL
  // To implement client access control to the RTSP server, do the following:
  authDB = new UserAuthenticationDatabase;
  authDB->addUserRecord("username1", "password1"); // replace these with real strings
  // Repeat the above with each <username>, <password> that you wish to allow
  // access to the server.
#endif

  // Creating the RTSP server:
  RTSPServer* rtspServer = RTSPServer::createNew(*env, 8554, authDB);
  if (rtspServer == NULL) {
    *env << "Failed to create RTSP server: " << env->getResultMsg() << "\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  char const* descriptionString
    = "Session streamed by \"testOnDemandRTSPServer\"";
 // A H.264 video elementary stream:
  {
    char const* streamName = "h264ESVideoTest";
    char const* inputFileName = "test1.264";
    ServerMediaSession* sms
      = ServerMediaSession::createNew(*env, streamName, streamName,
                      descriptionString);
    sms->addSubsession(H264VideoFileServerMediaSubsession
               ::createNew(*env, inputFileName, reuseFirstSource));
    rtspServer->addServerMediaSession(sms);

    announceStream(rtspServer, sms, streamName, inputFileName);
  }
    if (rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(80) || rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(8000) || rtspServer->setUpTunnelingOverHTTP(8080)) {
    *env << "\n(We use port " << rtspServer->httpServerPortNum() << " for optional RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling.)\n";
  } else {
    *env << "\n(RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling is not available.)\n";
  }

  env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(); // does not return

  return 0; // only to prevent compiler warning
}

static void announceStream(RTSPServer* rtspServer, ServerMediaSession* sms,
               char const* streamName, char const* inputFileName) {
  char* url = rtspServer->rtspURL(sms);
  UsageEnvironment& env = rtspServer->envir();
  env << "\n\"" << streamName << "\" stream, from the file \""
      << inputFileName << "\"\n";
  env << "Play this stream using the URL \"" << url << "\"\n";
  delete[] url;
}
```